# Scroll up to the success message once the embedded Google form is submitted

Tags: google-forms

How to scroll up to the success message once the embedded Google form is submitted, so that the user sees the message? I have a height of about 2000px and when it's done the submitted message is out of view and the user has to scroll up manually.

For example the form takes up the entire 2000px height and when submitted the success message is in the top 200px of the 2000px and the browser stays at the ≈scrolled 2000px height.

Answer (score 1):

The scroll bar is part of the web page where the Google Form is embedded. I don't think that it could capture the onSubmit event of the Google Form.

One workaround is to reduce the height of your form by splitting the questions through several sections so it will not be necessary the use of scroll bar.